# Images duplicates themselves

Tags: html, css

a newbie here trying to learn the basics av CSS-sprites and now I've spent some time to fix this problem without being able to complete the task.

My problem is that the image, fetched from CSS-sprite, is duplicating itself. Maybe you can spot the problem.

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="oneColFixCtr.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <h1>CSS Sprites</h1>

   <img src="sammansattbild1.png"/>


   <ul id="test1">
   <li>
<a class="item0" href="#" title=""/>
</li>
Original Bild



   </ul>
   <ul id="test2">

<li>
<a class="item05" href="#" title=""/>
</li>
PNG Bild, 4,3 BBP


   </ul>
   <ul id="test">

<li>
<a class="item1" href="#" title=""/>
</li>
JPEG 4 BPP
<li>
<a class="item2" href="#" title=""/>
</li>
2 BPP
<li>
<a class="item3" href="#" title=""/>
</li>
1 BPP
<li>
<a class="item4" href="#" title=""/>
</li>
0,5 BPP
<li>
<a class="item5" href="#" title=""/>
</li>
0,25 BPP
</ul>
    <!-- end .content --></div>
  <!-- end .container --></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS-file:

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }


#test { width: 128px; margin: 20px auto; }

#test li {
    list-style-type:none;
    font-size:1em;
}

#test li a {
    background-image:url('sammansattbild1.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    display: block;
    height: 180px;
}


#test1 { width: 128px;
position:absolute;
 }

#test1 li {

    font-size:1em;
}

#test1 li a {
    background-image:url('sammansattbild1.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    display: block;
    height: 180px;
}

#test2 { width: 128px;
position:absolute;
margin-left:160px; }

#test2 li {
    font-size:1em;
}

#test2 li a {
    background-image:url('sammansattbild1.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    display: block;
    height: 180px;
}

#test1 li a.item0 {background-position:0px 0px;}


#test2 li a.item05 {background-position:-160px 0px;}
#test2 li a:hover.item05 {background-position:0px 0px;}


#test li a.item1 {background-position:-100 0px;}
#test li a:hover.item1 {background-position:0px 0px;}


#test li a.item2 {background-position:-480px 0px;}
#test li a:hover.item2 {background-position:0px 0px;}

#test li a.item3 {background-position:-660px 0px;}
#test li a:hover.item3 {background-position:0px 0px;}

#test li a.item4 {background-position:-800px 0px;}
#test li a:hover.item4 {background-position:0px 0px;}

#test li a.item5 {background-position:-960px 0px;}
#test li a:hover.item5 {background-position:0px 0px;}
```

/thanks

edit: Image wanted: http://i.imgur.com/bW2AQNA.png

kcmello.imgur.com/all <- css sprit. Fiddle: jsfiddle.net/7oxrmj2z

Comment: To see what exactly is wrong with your css we would need to see the output and the pictures. Please upload your pictures somewhere and make a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) by inserting your code.

Comment: For starters, you are missing the closing tag for your anchors. `<a>` tags are not void elements therefore you need the corresponding `</a>`.

Comment: Can you fiddle this or make a code snippet that works here in Stackoverflow? http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: http://kcmello.imgur.com/all/ <- css sprit.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7oxrmj2z/

Comment: Structure of the task: http://imgur.com/WcURexB

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem after validating.

The problem lied that I had not added a closing tag to:

```
<a class="item1" href="#" title=""/>
```

after adding: `<a class="item1" href="#" title=""></a>`

The images stopped duplicate themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want, and what your problem exactly is, baut I think your code displays four times the `sammansattbild1.png` picture :

1)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <h1>CSS Sprites</h1>

    <img src="sammansattbild1.png"/>
```

2)

```
#test li a {
    background-image:url('sammansattbild1.png');
```

3)

```
#test1 li a {
    background-image:url('sammansattbild1.png');
```

4)

```
#test2 li a {
    background-image:url('sammansattbild1.png');
```

So here you have the fouroccurences of your image.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Also this one to      #test2 li a {
    background-image:url('sammantsattbild1.png);

Comment: The #test1 just have a different positions. Im trying to form it like, two images horizontal, and then the third to seventh images are vertical.

Comment: I don't really understand what you have and what you want. Can you put 2 schemes to your first post ?